# How to track SEO Conversion in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I've been trying to track the conversion rate of users acquired through organic search to direct (Users who discover the site through an organic medium and eventually start coming back to the site on their own through direct search). The way I decided to go about this was create a segment with a sequencing of the following kind-
[image: Screenshot of sequencing rule]
The results that I get are very counter-intuitive which leads me to think that maybe my understanding of how sequencing works is not correct. What could I change to get a measure of organic to direct search conversion?

Comment: Go to Conversions > Multi Channel Funnels > Top Conversion Paths. You will have that already sorted out. Play with the filters to get the data you need. I hope this was what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the scope of the segment from 'Sessions' to 'Users' should fetch you the desired result.
[image]